# Cartesian to spherical coordinate system

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

Hey I want to convert Cartesian to spherical coordinate system. I referred many site and for calculating elevation angle $\theta$ from positive z axis they all used formula $\arctan \frac { \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{z}$ but my problem is $\theta$ can be anything from 0 to 180 degrees but the range of inverse tan is from -90 to 90 so how is that online calculators gives angle greater than 90. For example take x y z with x and y positive and z negative so angle should be between 90 and 180 but inverse tan gives some negative angle. I tried with x=93.3 y=25 z=-65.8819 $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ gives 96.5926 $\arctan(96.5926)/(-65.8819)$ gives -55.7028 but correct answer is 124.30 degrees i guess
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just choose the range of inverse of tangent that fits your need.

That is, if $z = 0$, then $\theta = 90^\circ$. If $z < 0$, then $90^\circ<\theta\le180^\circ$ and $\theta$ satisfies $\tan \theta = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{z}$. If $z > 0$, then $0^\circ\le\theta<90^\circ$ and $\tan \theta = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{z}$. These cases come from your application.

For easier computation and to let your computer determine the cases for you, you can look up the function `atan2` which is very common among programming languages. Then your $\theta$ is

$$\theta = \text{atan2}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},z\right)$$